# SVG generated by AI not showing after include

Tags: javascript, html, svg, shapes

I have a .svg file generated using Adobe Illustrator. These is the structure of the SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="1068px" height="1671.49px" viewBox="0 0 1068 1671.49" enable-background="new 0 0 1068 1671.49" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <polygon fill="#C6C6C6" points="451.07,1979.34 451.07,1979.34 450.8,1979.17 448.72,1978.82 448.6,1978.71 448.34,1978.59 
        447.71,1978.36 448.01,1978.33 450.2,1978.3 452.53,1978.76 451.35,1979.08 451.73,1979.29     "/>
<!-- more polygon shapes -->
</g>
</svg>
```

Then I include it using the `<embed>` tag like this in my .html file. Structure of the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="shape1"></div>
        <div id="shape2"></div>        
        <div id="shape3"></div>
        <div id="embed_svg">
            <embed src="my_svg_file.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Notes:

- I don't think that is browser support related since I've drawn 3 HTML5 shapes using the raphael.js HTML5 library and they work perfectly. (tried on chrome and firefox)
- Including the file doesn't work as it should. The browser seems to parse it but it just doesn't seem to display it.

Comment: What browser you're testing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The co-ordinates in your shapes are very similar so the polygon covers a very very tiny part of the viewBox area.

If you change the viewBox of the `<svg>` element to viewBox="448 1977 5 10" the shape will be displayed as the visible region now more closely matches the polygon co-ordinates, alternatively make the polygon bigger.

Comment: ok.. now it seems to display the top right corner.. but I can't figure out how did you thinked on this matter.. how can I make to display all the SVG, because I know the width="1068px" height="1671.49px".. why doesn't viewBox="0 0 1068 1671" doesn't display anything.. because it starts from top right corner and displays all that is needed

Comment: because the viewBox covers a large area and the polygon is less than one pixel in size within that area. If you make the viewBox cover an area just larger than the polygon you'll see the shape.

Comment: thanks.. then it seems the export process from AdobeIllustrator is wrong.. any ideeas on this process.. if I select save for web and I uncheck the 'Clip for Artboard' option.. it works ok the generated image.. but i have no such option when saving as svg